How to break temporarily from loop in repeat zone
Here is a simple node setup. With each iteration, it generates an ico-sphere and places it 2 units to the right. What if I wanted only the 3rd ico-sphere to be placed 3 units to the right? How would I do that without changing the position of the other ico-spheres?


This sounds like a wrong way problem. That is, you have a bigger picture in mind, and you’ve incorrectly decided that this is the best way to do it. There is a way to do this, but it’s not going to be very flexible. What is your ultimate goal?

I am working on a node setup to mimic music notation software. I have a node group that allows you to generate a note, and select its parameters like note length, note pitch, accidental, and dynamic. I could probably duplicate the node group and assign its parameters to create the next note. But it would be nice if I could generate the group in a loop and change the parameters as I go. I don't know if I make sense.

You can't break repeat zones like you can do in programmation. You could add a field that represents the x-position. At each step, you either add 2 or 3 depending on some conditions. Overall, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. (It appears it's what you have already done ?)

You can use a switch node and the iteration property of the repeat zone to isolate the third icosphere.


the switch could control the offset being 2 or 3
